# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10695.write. : java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, dataframe, amazon-s3, pyspark, hive

I've a 4000 column Pyspark dataframe and about 3000 of them happened to be empty columns. While I write the output to S3, I'm getting the below error. Please be noted, the same code works fine when the empty column count is under 500 and the rest of 3500 columns are with data populated. So I believe the issue could be with too many empty columns in the DF.

Error Below:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10695.write.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.isStreaming(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$isStreaming$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$isStreaming$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:84)
```